# Presentations of exotic 4-manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, 4-manifolds, triangulations, kirby-calculus

**TLDR** I want to see more examples of exotic $4$-manifold (hopefully connected, simply connected, oriented, and closed).

Are there known presentations of $4$-manifolds $M$ with exotic structures, whether in terms of Kirby linky data, PL-triangulations, or any other constructions? There are a few given in Akbulut's book [1], but they are $4$-manifolds with boundaries.

Mainly, I am looking for those $M$ that are oriented, connected, simply-connected and closed. But really, any pointers to any example with exotic smooth structures are appreciated.

[1] 4-Manifolds - Selman Akbulut

Comment: Mainly using gauge theoretic invariants one can detect such 4-manifolds ( Akbulut's book is great source). In my best knowledge, knot surgery, rational blow down and cork-twists  are possibly only known techniques to obtain something exotic. If you search those key words in google, you may find more sources to read.

Comment: BTW I still found your question a little confusing. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: I believe the answer to the OP's question is "yes".  But the question is fairly non-specific.  4-manifolds with "exotic" structures exist, so certainly they are presented in various ways, by various sources.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee I want to see more examples of exotic $4$-manifolds.. sorry my original post is mouthful.

Comment: @Student As I said, try to google those key words and you will find various papers. But not many examples are known. We possibly only know the tip of the iceberg (maybe not even that).

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee I see.. thanks for your comment. I think I asked the question badly.. My impression when I was looking for examples is that they seem scattered around, and it seems hard to find a place where many examples are compiled together. It's good to know that not many examples are known yet.

Comment: @Student yup, research on "exotic" 4-manifold topology is an wide open field. You may find some lecture notes where some examples are compiled together. (I cannot think of one top off my head right now.)

Answer (score 10):

I guess that this is as explicit and low-tech as it gets: if $X$ is a K3 surface (i.e. a non-singular quartic hypersurface in $\mathbb{CP}^3$, with the complex orientation), then $X \# \overline{\mathbb{CP}}{}^2$ and $3\mathbb{CP}^2 \# 20\overline{\mathbb{CP}}{}^2$ are an exotic pair.

To see that they are homeomorphic, we use that odd indefinite forms are diagonalisable and then Freedman's theorem. (Ok, and that complex projective hypersurfaces are simply-connected, by Lefschetz's theorem.) To see that they are not diffeomorphic, we use that Kähler surfaces have (some) non-zero Seiberg–Witten invariant, while anything written as a connected sum of indefinite pieces doesn't. (In particular, the same argument applies to any hypersurface of $\mathbb{CP}^3$ of degree at least 4; in this case, blowing up/connected summing with $\overline{\mathbb{CP}}{}^2$ is only needed in even degrees.)

This is just the tip of the iceberg of the tip of the iceberg that Anubhav mentioned in his comment.

**EDIT** (06/03/2024): Levine, Lidman, and Piccirillo's [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.08130) [LLP] fits the bill. They give explicit constructions of exotic 4-manifolds using Kirby diagrams (and explicitly computing some Heegaard Floer diffeomorphism invariants).

While I'm at it with the edits... About the example I mentioned above: one can give explicit handle diagrams for the K3 and for its exotic companion (see Gompf and Stipsicz's book), so those examples where explicit too. There's an important difference with [LLP]: the original computation of the SW invariants of the K3 and of $3\mathbb{CP}^2 \# 20\overline{\mathbb{CP}}{}^2$ was done using properties of SW (an something similar with HF), while in [LLP] they compute the invariants from the handle decomposition.

Answer (score 4):

If you're still interested in this, I've been working on triangulations of exotic 4-manifolds for some time now. I've implemented an algorithm to produce triangulations of 4-manifolds from Kirby diagrams, and using this I've obtained triangulations of some bounded exotic pairs. See https://arxiv.org/abs/2402.15087 for the details and data --- again note that the exotic pairs I've constructed triangulations of are those you may already be aware of and have boundary (in the linked paper, I cone all boundaries to a point, but in forthcoming work I look at ones with 'real' boundary). The long term goal/big picture idea here, among others, is that by doing all this combinatorially/computationally, then eventually we might be able to generate (triangulations of) *new* exotica at our pleasure.

Comment: So good to see you paper. I will read it in details. Do you also have code that implements your algorithm? How heuristic is the heuristics you provided? Will you implement them in near future?

Comment: The utility for triangulating framed links (2-handles only) is available in the latest version of Regina; the code for the "expanded" algorithm for Kirby diagrams with 1-handles isn't available publicly yet (but should be out soonish). There is a link to the code for the simplification heuristic in the paper (currently this requires knowledge of building against the Regina libraries, but again should become built-in functionality soon). The simplification heuristic is just that - a heuristic, but as it turns out, a fairly effective one :) Happy to answer any other questions if you have them